Кнопка очистки корзины woocommerce
Не понимаю как можно сделать кнопку очистки всей корзины на сайте. Я хочу что бы когда пользователь заходил на страницу "корзина" была кнопка "очистить всё" с соответствующем функционалом. Почему-то код и плагины из интернета не работают.

При нажатии на кнопку очистки корзины делаете ajax запрос на сервер, с помощью функции очищаете корзину и отдаете успешный результат или ошибку в случае если произошла ошибка, а после успешного выполнения запроса перезагружаете страницу
